# Finding Lowest Common Ancestor in a binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I am looking for a way to find lowest common ancestor in a binary tree.

Note : It is binary tree not binary search tree and we don't have any parent pointer. Moreover if we are trying to find a LCA for a parent(P) and any of its child(C) then the LCA will be immediate parent of P.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor - all you need is there

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i have already been to that link. I am looking for an algorithm here.

Comment: "*In a tree data structure where each node points to its parent, the lowest common ancestor can be easily determined by finding the first intersection of the paths from v and w to the root*."

Comment: I already told in my question that we don't have a parent pointer.

Comment: It's not hard to adopt. 1. Find and store paths from root to both of your nodes. 2. Process the stored paths simultaneously until the first difference. The node prior to the difference is your LCA

Comment: I am looking for something in run time O(n) and space complexity O(1).